# How can I make this code case insensitive?

Tags: shell, unix

How can I make this code case insensitive?

```
test "${string#*$word}" != "$string" && echo "$word found in $string
```

Comment: with test, you can't. you'll have to `tr` the case of both strings into all-upper or all-lower, then compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` to convert both strings to the same case and then compare them.

Example: `echo $string | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`